# xml markers have wrong encoding

Tags: javascript, php, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with google maps markers. I want to use polish characters in the names of the markers. As i have in my db. This is the file which i use to create proper (afaik) XML.

```
function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
}

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  $test = $row['name'];
  //$test2 = string utf8_encode ( string $test );
  echo 'name="' . $test . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'city="' . $row['city'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';
```

I get proper output from my db using this file (browser display polish characters properly) but when i create a map using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBdj-LlQrTCj6bQcAq4fxONy9MaZcXvfc8"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.046465, 19.913828),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("markergen.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("city");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>

  </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="load()">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Then i get whole data, but without correctly displayed polish characters.
I know that i should probably use

```
string utf8_encode ( string $data )
```

but i did try to put it in first file to convert data and fail.
So my question is where i should put it exactly into my code? Or is there any other/better option to do this.

EDIT: 
I'm now trying to use DOM objects like this:

```
<?php
require("../test1/phpsqlinfo_dbinfo.php");


// Start XML file, create parent node

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    exit();
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}


// Select all the rows in the markers table

$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);


header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("city", $row['city']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

But now i have marker inside of marker in results like: `<marker><marker>...</marker></marker>` with data ofc. How to fix it? Still i'm not sure that data are correctly encoded but should be.

Comment: You never tell MySQL what encoding to use. Is your data already UTF-8? Or it's just using whatever database default encoding was in effect when you created the tables?

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not use utf8_encode().

You should however use ext/mysqli or ext/pdo (not the old, depreacted and removed ext/mysql). Set the connection encoding to UTF-8 to get all strings as UTF-8 from the database.

Then use an XML library (DOM or XMLWriter) to generate the XML output. The libraries will encode/escape special characters as needed.

It will provide the missing XML declaration, too.

Comment: Well great thanks for reply. I tried something like this: